# Help identifying old board game

Tags: identify-this-game

Does anyone know what game this is? It seems to be a 12x12 grid with the outside rows used to mark a winner of a row. It appears that each box can be slid to reveal a color. Picture is from the late 70's.

[image: game]

Comment: If a line is formed connecting the two players, are the  outside rows used for scoring parallel or perpendicular to that line? Both?

Comment: Try this list: http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/32366/games-played-1212-grid/

Comment: That somewhat looks like an old multiplication table toy - it'd have the numbers 0 through 10 on one side, and numbers 0 through 10 on the other axis, and you'd slide a key to see what their multiplied value was.  I had one of those as a kid - although mine was blue plastic.

Comment: It looks like a Con-Tac-Tix board (1968). It would help to know if two different colours can be shown when a box is slid to reveal a colour. https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/337244/skjode-skjern-danishenglish-edition

Comment: Based on this photo alone, I'm not prepared to jump to the conclusion that this is a game at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that it is a memory matching game.

The players would place a sheet of images or colours underneath the playing surface.

The players would then take turns, opening 2 slots with the objective of revealing identical images or colours inside those slots. Successfully doing so would obtain a victory point.